# Getting a dictionary with no column info

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I had a pandas dataframe and wanted to turn it into a dictionary that I could search. 
The dataframe looks like this:

```
           1
   0
   ko1    836
   ko2    786
   ko3    898
```

There were no column names so the headers were automatically set as 1 and 0 and I made column 0 the index. When I made it into a dictionary using

```
y = x.to_dict(orient="index")
```

The dictionary output looked like this

```
{ko1:{1:836},ko2:{1:786},ko3:{1:898}}
```

How could I make it into a dicrionary like this:

```
{ko1:836,ko2:786,ko3:898}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just slice the Series first and then call the method:

```
x[1].to_dict()
Out: {'ko1': 836, 'ko2': 786, 'ko3': 898}
```